# Photogrammetry tool to create 3D model of glasses (transparent, reflective, homegeneous object)

Tags: photography, 3d

I am trying to make a 3d model of my glasses. I have looked at photogrammetry software. In my research,  I found out photogrammetry has issues with transparent, reflective, homogeneous objects. I used Qlone which is 3D scanner app to find out for myself if this was the case.  The app only picked up the dark parts of the arms and nose area.  So I have looked at other software's but they seem to be mostly for larger objects and landscapes.

As of now I only need the front and side of my glasses to be on the model but it needs to be close to life like as possible. I need the model to be compatible with unity as well.

I would very much appreciate recommendations or any suggests on the best way for me to conduct this project. Is photogrammetry the right way of going about it?

Answer (score 3):

You may find that you can apply a chalk spray to the object to create a suitable surface for photogrammetry. Many image scanning devices for 3D modeling have problems with transparent and reflective surfaces and such sprays are frequently the solution. As with all such products, test it on a non-critical surface to ensure the glasses will not be damaged. I have such a product and find that once dry, it wipes off easily, as well as washes off easily. It's also possible to accidentally smudge the surface, so plan accordingly by attaching mounting pins or suspension lines for moving between the spray area and the scanning area.